# How are people adding public comments to their Craft sites?

Tags: comments, guest

It's not been asked as a broad question here yet, but we've all wondered: how does one go adding comments to a Craft site, such as those you'd find on a blog?

I've either used or been aware of...

1. Tacking [Disqus](https://disqus.com/) (JavaScript) comments onto pages.
2. Integrating [Google+ comments](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-do-i-implement-google-comments-on-a-craft-site).
3. Using a dedicated Craft Section for comments and relating each to a post, collecting submissions with [Guest Entries](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/guest-entries).

Are there others out there? Would an expert comment engineer care to answer authoritatively?

Comment: Looks like you're the expert!

Comment: Color me skeptical. Victor In, Christian Seelbach and Lindsey D must have each missed this one.

Comment: I've take a look about this plugin : [https://github.com/engram-design/Comments/tree/master/comments](https://github.com/engram-design/Comments/tree/master/comments)
But it doesn't seem to work for me. I've got errors on submit and the plugin in CP doesn't look like the one in there screenshots. Since, I'm currently working on mine. For now, I already have it in php and SQL. But to follow the style of Craft I will do it in plugin style.

Comment: Not sure what to make of this "answer"... You're suggesting another method, but also saying that it didn't work for you. Did you intend to post this as a comment, instead of an "answer"?

Comment: It's both. How are people adding public comments to their Craft sites? I added mine with SQL and PHP all write by hand. I've tried too the plugin mentionned. It's a GIt and I talk to the DEV from this plugin and told me he fixed some problem with his last commit on the master. And will fix some other too. So the plugin will eventually work correctly and it will be a very nice solution then. So I suggest and comment and give answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe above is essentially your options. If you use built in sections for comments, you can probably make them more secure from spam by using [Dukt's OAuth](https://dukt.net/craft/oauth) plugin to require a log in from a more reputable site.

Other third-party options include:

- [Intense Debate](http://intensedebate.com/) (from the makers of WordPress)
- [LiveFyre Comments](http://web.livefyre.com/comments/)
- [Facebook Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm personally using Disqus for most things; though Facebook Comments make sense for some sites as well.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there are two main options: [Comments plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/) and Disqus.

With Disqus, you can either add it to the website manually or use [Disqus plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/disqus) if you want to use Single Sign-On functionality.

Here's the article on my blog that describes how to add Disqus manually to Craft website:

http://craftsnippets.com/articles/adding-disqus-comments-to-craft-cms-website